# suddenly wifi no adapter found issue ocured

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, ubuntu-drivers

Here is my PC config.
I have checked all old query and suggestion but that are not helping me. please suggest me how can I get back wifi adapter.

```
inxi -Fxz

    System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-100-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Notebook v: Type1ProductConfigId 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: HP model: 81ED v: 62.36 serial: <filter> UEFI [Legacy]: Insyde 
  v: F.21 date: 10/27/2016 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 16.2 Wh condition: 20.5/41.4 Wh (49%) 
  model: Hewlett-Packard PABAS0241231 status: Charging 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i3-7100U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Amber Lake rev: 9 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 19200 
  Speed: 1164 MHz min/max: 400/2400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1164 2: 1223 
  3: 1280 4: 1149 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: modesetting 
  unloaded: fbdev,vesa tty: N/A 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-100-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet 
  vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 bus ID: 01:00.0 
  IF: enp1s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-1: br-7f45a238a125 state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-2: br-a4750d83537e state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-3: docker0 state: down mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-4: ppp0 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A 
  IF-ID-5: veth38a943f state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full 
  mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-6: veth3b69d38 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full 
  mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-7: veth4998626 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full 
  mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-8: veth90366ae state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full 
  mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 262.27 GiB (28.2%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ01ABD100 size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 285.42 GiB used: 81.32 GiB (28.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7 
  ID-2: swap-1 size: 3.81 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: 29.8 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 404 Uptime: 8m Memory: 11.61 GiB used: 3.49 GiB (30.0%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 
  inxi: 3.0.38
```

**I tried with this command**

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

**no output found**

In Below command found this output

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:81ed]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @ChanganAuto no output found on this command.

Comment: That means no WiFi card is being detected at all. Two possible scenarios: (1) It was somehow disabled in UEFI ("BIOS") or (2) It broke or is no longer properly connected. So, first check UEFI settings and if enabled or if there isn't any such setting (means always ON and controlled by the OS only) try removing it and reconnecting it (re-seat).

Comment: @ChanganAuto I checked BIOS is ok. So I have to check hardware am I right?

Comment: Yes, you should, if the WiFi is removable. Always try re-seating after cleaning contacts.

Comment: Based on the information in `Machine`, you should have a `RTL8723BE` PCIe wireless device in there under `0280` rather than `0200`. That said, does your notebook have a hardware switch on the side to control the wireless radios? Something like "Airplane mode" ... ?

Comment: @matigo yes  f12  button has "Airoplane icon" but that button not working now. due to wifi adapter not found.

Comment: Could you humour me by pressing [Fn]+[F12] (as though the wireless device *was* working) to see if it becomes visible? Some machines enable airplane mode by disconnecting power at the hardware level, making the device appear unplugged/non-existent 